# Adding a configuration option to the Action Bar - Android 4.0+

Tags: android, configuration, android-actionbar

What is the simplest way to add one option to the action bar for an Android App (4.0 & above)?

Answer (score 1):

Menu inflation is the easiest way to add entries to the menu.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html